# Tap gesture on buttons response randomly in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, gesture

I have a My Profile form in my app. In the form I have some buttons. Among them 5 buttons are used to present custom drop down menus to select Sax, Blood, Nationality, and so on. However, when I tap these buttons sometime they response some time don't. For example, if I tap them 10 time they response 2 or 3 times. Some time they work for long tap. I have spent days on this matter, but could not identify any problem in my code. Is there anyone who faced this sort of problems? Could anyone figure out what is the actual problem. By the way, all other buttons in my app working absolutely fine.

[image: My Profile form]

This is the code for first 3 buttons in red rectangle in the picture

```
import SwiftUI

struct FormPartTwoView: View {
    @Binding var gender: String
    @Binding var blood: String
    @Binding var nationality: String
    
    @Binding var showingGenderPicker: Bool
    @Binding var showingBloodGroupPicker: Bool
    @Binding var showingNationalityPicker: Bool
    @ObservedObject var userProfile = UserProfileViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var userProfileUpdate = UserProfileUpdateViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingGenderPicker.toggle()
                    self.showingBloodGroupPicker = false
                    self.showingNationalityPicker = false
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Gender", text: self.$gender)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .disabled(true)
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(Color("Border2"), lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                Button(action: {
                    self.showingBloodGroupPicker.toggle()
                    self.showingGenderPicker = false
                    self.showingNationalityPicker = false
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Blood", text: self.$blood)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .disabled(true)
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(Color("Border2"), lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                Button(action: {
                    self.showingNationalityPicker.toggle()
                    self.showingGenderPicker = false
                    self.showingBloodGroupPicker = false
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Nationality", text: self.$nationality)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .disabled(true)
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(Color("Border2"), lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 40)
        }
    }
}

struct FormPartTwoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FormPartTwoView(gender: .constant(""), blood: .constant(""), nationality: .constant(""), showingGenderPicker: .constant(false), showingBloodGroupPicker: .constant(false), showingNationalityPicker: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

This is the code for second tow Buttons:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FormPartFiveView: View {
    @Binding var district: String
    @Binding var upazila: String
    @Binding var postcode: String
    
    @Binding var showingUpazilaPicker: Bool
    @Binding var showingDistrictPicker: Bool
    @ObservedObject var userProfileUpdate = UserProfileUpdateViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingDistrictPicker.toggle()
                    self.showingUpazilaPicker = false
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("\(self.district == "" ? "District" : self.district)")
                            .foregroundColor(self.district == "" ? Color.gray : Color.black)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3.2, height: 40)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(Color("Border2"), lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingUpazilaPicker.toggle()
                    self.showingDistrictPicker = false
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("\(self.upazila == "" ? "Upazila" : self.upazila)")
                            .foregroundColor(self.upazila == "" ? Color.gray : Color.black)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3.2, height: 40)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(Color("Border2"), lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                VStack {
                    TextField("Postcode", text: self.$postcode)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .font(.system(size: 13))
                .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(Color("Border2"), lineWidth: 1)
                )
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 40)
        }
    }
}

struct FormPartFiveView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FormPartFiveView(district: .constant(""), upazila: .constant(""), postcode: .constant(""), showingUpazilaPicker: .constant(false), showingDistrictPicker: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you put TextField into Button? I assume this is the reason, so just separate them Button with Text label and TextField separately.

Comment: I have tried with just Text view as well. But still same behaviour.